# Calculating NDVI with Rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, ndvi, rasterio

I'm using Rasterio to read GeoTIFF files from Landsat 8 and calculate NDVI into a new GeoTIFF file.

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy
import rasterio
import subprocess

with rasterio.drivers(CPL_DEBUG=True):

    # Read raster bands directly to Numpy arrays.
    #
    dsRed = rasterio.open('downloads/LC81970212013122LGN01/LC81970212013122LGN01_B3.TIF')
    bandRed = dsRed.read_band(1)

    dsNir = rasterio.open('downloads/LC81970212013122LGN01/LC81970212013122LGN01_B5.TIF')
    bandNir = dsNir.read_band(1)

    ndvi = numpy.zeros(dsRed.shape, dtype=rasterio.uint16)

    ndvi_upper = bandNir + bandRed
    ndvi_lower = bandNir - bandRed

    ndvi = ndvi_lower / ndvi_upper

    kwargs = dsRed.meta
    kwargs.update(
        dtype=rasterio.uint16,
        count=1,
        compress='lzw')

    with rasterio.open('example-total.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        dst.write_band(1, ndvi.astype(rasterio.uint16))


# Dump out gdalinfo's report card and open the image.
info = subprocess.check_output(['gdalinfo', '-stats', 'example-total.tif'])
print(info)

subprocess.call(['open', 'example-total.tif'])
```

But it isn't really producing the result I was hoping for.

I'm probably getting the data types wrong, I'm not too familiar with Python and NumPy.

The resulting image is all black. If I multiple the result array by e.g. 1000 it becomes visible, but it isn't the correct values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I would use bands 4(red) and 5(nir) for Landsat 8 according to the description of the [OLI instrument](http://landsat.usgs.gov/ldcm_vs_previous.php), and 3(red) and 4(NIR) for the Landsat TM and ETM.

Second, you define an output in dtype=rasterio.uint16, but NDVI should be a float (between -1 and 1). You should either initialize your raster as dtype=rasterio.float32 , or multiply your values by 1000 in your code, ans store as int16.

```
ndvi = numpy.zeros(dsRed.shape, dtype=rasterio.float32)

ndvi = (bandNIR.astype(float)-bandRed.astype(float))/(bandNIR+bandRed)

kwargs = dsRed.meta
kwargs.update(
    dtype=rasterio.float32,
    count=1,
    compress='lzw')

with rasterio.open('example-total.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
    dst.write_band(1, ndvi.astype(rasterio.float32))
```

Comment: Works better using band 4 (I thought band 3 was red). Instead of being all black, all countryside is now dark. The same dark color all over. Is it supposed to be lower / upper, or is it upper / lower? Changing it the result seems more correct.

Comment: it has to be with the dif on top. Note that dark does not necessarily mean that you have a problem : it could only be a DISPLAY issue.

Comment: @MartinHN Landsat 8 band 4 is red, Landsat 4-7 (TM and ETM+) band 3 is red - http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php

Comment: @radouxju It probably is a display issue. For display it would also make more sense to visualise similar to this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/NDVI_062003.png

Comment: Although, looking at the stats of the resulting file it seems weird that none of the values are below zero?

  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65000
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1321.0759915166
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=2195.2510197044

Comment: @MartinHN Those stats indeed don't make sense for NDVI. I've tried a code update in my answer, but I am not familiar with rasterio. Note that this could be done with gdal_calc or OTBBandMath

Comment: @MartinHN By the way, you should not accept my answer if it didn't solve your problem: maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: I haven't heard of OTBBandMath. Your code produce the same stats, but the resulting image is a lot better. Very close to one I generated using the code in this repo: https://github.com/ibamacsr/indicar-tools, only a little darker but that's just display.

Comment: here is a link if you want to look at OTB https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu8.html#x17-160001.3.4

Comment: @radouxju Hi, I'm trying to use this python code but it crashes. and the error. python.exe has stopped working, kernel dies in Anaconda.

Comment: @MartinHN, I've tried to used a clipped image (to use a small size image) but it still crashes. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @MartinHN, 2 years later here. I have the same issue - the output's pixel values are ok if restretched between -1 and 1; however, the raster stats appear as Minimum=537.000, Maximum=35834.000, Mean=6468.495, StdDev=4490.833 no matter what GIS program I try to open it in. Even displaying the histogram in QGIS shows the original band values and not NDVI - very very odd. Has anyone solved this yet?